# MobaXTerm how to create your own plugin?

Tags: terminal

**Problem**
I see all these plugins from MobaXTerm, but I don't know how to make my own. I see no links to any tutorials or whatever. Is there even a way to do it?

**What I really want (XY problem)**
I want to create my own commands. I want these to be available on each server I go to and I don't want to add each of these to my bin and .bash_profile etc. I think plugin is the way to go.

**Even more background**
I am not that good in shell programming, but I can program java. I created a jar which handles my commands. So I have created my own linux script on my local environment to test all these things. They work, but I dont want to 'export' them to other servers. Seems like a bad idea to do.

Answer (score 0):

MobaXterm plugins are just Windows or Cygwin executables packaged in a .mxt3 file which is just a standard ZIP archive with a specific structure.

Read this from the MobaXterm FAQ:

> I would like to create a new plugin for MobaXterm. How can I do that?
>
> - Download an existing plugin file (for instance "Midnight commander")
> - Rename plugin extension from ".mxt3" to ".zip"
> - Open the ".zip" file You will notice that creating MobaXterm plugins only consists in putting the required commands (executables, libraries
>   and configuration files) into a ZIP file, keeping the same folders
>   tree than in MobaXterm ("/bin", "/lib", "/usr", "/etc").
> - If you want to add a simple Windows program (exe file), you will just have to copy the executable file into the "/bin" directory,
>   create the ZIP archive, rename it to ".mxt3" and put it in the same
>   directory than MobaXterm executable.
> - If you want to add a Linux program, you will have to get it from the Cygwin project or to recompile it using make, gcc, g++ or other
>   compilers that are available from the MobaXterm "Development" plugin.

Remember MobaXterm's terminal is just Cygwin, so you may be able to cross compile some packages within Moba by simply installing the necessary compiler tools.